# Is it possible to close all files with content that matches a regular expression on Vim?

Tags: regular-expression, file

Let's say I have opened many files on Vim with `vim file1 file2 file3`... And their content is like the following:

file1:

```
random content
random content
stringThatMatchesRegex
random content
```

file2:

```
random content
random content
random content
```

file3:

```
stringThatMatchesRegex
random content
random content
random content
```

Considering I could have `n` files opened like that, I'd like to find a way of closing all files that match `stringThatMatchesRegex`, so I'd like to close undesirable files with a regular expresssion. In this example, only `file2` would remain open. I know I could close single files using `:bd` on Vim, but I have no idea how to implement this `if` condition. Is it possible? Can I close files that have a line or lines that match a regular expression?

Comment: Whilst it is likely possible to write a vimscript function to do this, can you expand on your use case? This may be an XY problem; fastidious management of buffers can sometimes, but not always, be a sign of a vim workflow that can be optimised.

Comment: @AndrewHo-Lee Actually, I'm receiving a list of files from an external application, this list could reach hundreds of files inside a specific category. I thought of opening those files with Vim because I can easily edit those files by creating a macro that goes to the next file... So with a simple macro I end up editing many files at once. I honestly don't know if there's a straightforward way of closing files like that on Vim. If not, perhaps filtering the files before they're opened would be a better solution since I'm already receiving this list inside a bash script.

Comment: I suspect that filtering before you try and open in vim would be the more sane way of doing it.  For example, to open all files in a directory that do not contain the string `not_me`, you could do `vim \`find . -type f -exec grep -qvs 'not_me' {} \; -print\``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to populate the quickfix list with matches then use `:cfdo` to execute `:bdelete`

```
:vimgrep /pat/ ##
:cfdo bdelete
```

Even though the files are closed the files are still in the argument-list. Remove them via `:argdelete` with `%` to represent the current file

```
:vimgrep /pat/ ##
:cfdo argdelete % | bdelete
```

Additionally, I think it might be worth looking into `:Cfilter` and the quickfix list to do a series of manipulations. Use `:cdo`/`:cfdo` to run commands on the given buffers. Use `:cnext`/`:cprev`/`:cnfile`/`:cpfile` to navigate between files. Filter with `:Cfilter`

```
:cexpr argv()
:packadd cfilter
:Cfilter! /pat/
```

If you are going to be cycling buffers by hand I would suggest some mappings for `:next`/`:prev`. It would also be good to have mappings for the quickfix list. I use Tim Pope's [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired). Here are some example mappings:

```
nnoremap [A :first<cr>
nnoremap [a :prev<cr>
nnoremap ]a :next<cr>
nnoremap ]A :last<cr>
nnoremap [Q :cfirst<cr>
nnoremap [q :cprev<cr>
nnoremap [<c-q> :cpfile<cr>
nnoremap ]<c-q> :cnfile<cr>
nnoremap ]q :cnext<cr>
nnoremap ]Q :clast<cr>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :vimgrep
:h :grep
:h :cfdo
:h :bdelete
:h :_##
:h :argdelete
:h :_%
:h :cnfile
:h :cexpr
:h argv()
:h :Cfilter
:h :packadd
```

Comment: According to what I read on `:h` this answer should work. But in my case the `:bd` or `:bdelete`: is not working as I expected. If I finish this logic and then I use `:n` and `:N` I'm still capable of going forward and backwards through the files that should be closed.... There's still something missing.

Comment: Of course you can use `:next`/`:prev` to advance to the next file in the Argument List. It will simply re-open the file. If you want to remove a file from the arglist you need to do something like `:argdelete`. e.g. `:cfdo bd | .argdelete`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer doesn't work. Have you tested this answer with three files as I show in my example? When I make it with 3 files it seems to work, but if I add a fourth file that doesn't match the regex it doesn't work anymore. In my specific case, I can't assume that I'll have only one file that doesn't match the regex. My example was with three files but the number of files that doesn't match the regex will vary, as well as the number of files that match the regex...

Comment: @raylight perhaps you could explain what happens when it doesnt work?

Comment: I have ran a test. It is best to do the `:argdelete %` before the `:bdelete`, so that `%` represents the current filename. Although I think removing from the arglist is enough and the `:bd` is unnecessary for this task

Comment: Thanks, by having `:argdelete %` before the `:bdelete` it works in different situations now.

Answer (score 0):

In tab view it is generally easy to see open tabs. Please open files in tabs:

```
'vim -p <file list>'
```

Run regex and commands as:

```
:tabdo g:stringThatMatchesRegex: | q
```

Same can be done with :cfdo instead of (bd) buffer deletion you need to close the file using (q)

```
:cfdo g:stringThatMatchesRegex: | q
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I suppose instead of `:quit` you could use `:tabclose` here; also, why the bar `|` after `g/regex/`?

Comment: Hi, bar is for separating >1 commands. And quit or tab close both should work. I prefer q as it is short.

Comment: Also if you are not in tabs mode. then q will close your buffer that's what was wanted.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that the bar was separating the global command (which defaults to printing) from the quit, so that both were arguments to `tabdo`/`cfdo`; for some reason I thought you had intended to run `:g/pat/quit` on each tab, which (in reflection) makes little sense. Some [edit]s to clarify might be nice. Note that you can get inline code in markdown by surrounding text with single backticks (\`)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I edited the answer and added space.