# How can I keep open buffers whose contents match a pattern and delete the rest?

Tags: multiple-files, vimgrep

Let's say I have three files opened in my buffer list: `file1`,`file2` and `file3`. I know that if I use the command `:vimgrep /pattern/ ##` I'll populate the quickfix list with the files that have the `pattern` that I have determined on `vimgrep`. Also, if I use `:vimgrep /PATTERN/ ## | cfdo argdelete % | bdelete` I'll close all files in buffer that are inside my quickfix list, remaining only the ones that don't match the `pattern`.

So far, everything is fine. However, I'd like to be able to do the opposite, to **keep open** all **files** in buffer that **match a regular expression** while closing the ones that don't match it. How can I do it?

Comment: If this isn't possible then using `'grepprg'` with external (shell-based) grep might get you where you want to go.

Comment: @BLayer I see, considering that I have one list of files on my buffer list and another list of files on my quickfix list. Is it possible to get the difference between these two lists somehow? At first sight it seems like it would be simpler for me.

Comment: `grep -v` show the lines that do not match the pattern... Try `grep -L` for the files that don't have any lines matching the pattern. (Not sure if that's enough to populate the quick fix list with it using `:grep` command, but maybe try that and see how far it takes you.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you find a solution?

Comment: @BLayer Actually, no... When I made this question I misinterpreted the quickfix way of working. On [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/30963/is-it-possible-to-close-all-files-with-content-that-matches-a-regular-expression) I learned about a way of closing all files in buffer that matched a regular expression. That's possible with `:vimgrep /exp/ ## | cfdo argdelete % | bdelete`... The goal of this question here was to do the opposite, to keep open all files that match a regular expression. However, getting the inverted pattern on the quicklist wouldn't solve this issue.

Comment: @BLayer I understood what `grep -L` could do but I didn't manage to complete the solution of what I had in mind with it.

Comment: It can work using that method. You just have to get `'grepprg'` and `'grepformat'` right. I'll add an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap:

- OP wanted to populate quickfix list with buffers that DON'T match pattern given to `:vimgrep`.
- I suggested that `'grepprg'` could be used if `:vimgrep` couldn't.
- OP revised requirements based on better understanding of quickfix: wants to DELETE those same buffers.
- OP found a solution for the IS matching case and quickfix: `:vimgrep /exp/ ## | cfdo argdelete % | bdelete`
- ...but didn't think the inverse could be done analogously.

In fact, my original suggestion is still valid even with the new goal. This is how you can do it with command-line grep and `'grepprg'`:

```
:set grepprg=grep\ -L
:set grepformat=%f
:grep PATTERN ##
:cfdo argdelete % | bdelete
```

The key things here are to

1. Specify command line grep with the flag (`-L`) that returns names of files that DO NOT include the given pattern.
2. Change `'grepformat'` to account for grep only returning filename (`%f`) and not line numbers.

The rest is nearly identical to the is matching case except we use `:grep` instead of `:vimgrep` and we don't surround the pattern with delimiters (e.g. `//`).

I did a quick test with six buffers loaded, four of which contained text matching my pattern of choice. Ran all of the above and was left with just the other two buffers.

**Update:** Some feedback from @raylight (OP):

Since I work a lot with snippets on shortcuts I've adapted it for one line like

```
:set grepprg=grep\ -L | set grepformat=%f | grep 'expression' ## | cfdo argd % | bd
```

The expression seems to work better when it's around single quotes for some reason too (I've tested with a word containing ` and it didn't work without the single quotes)

Comment: Cool, that was exactly what I was looking for when I made the question... Since I work a lot with snippets on shortcuts I've adapted it for one line like `:set grepprg=grep\ -L | set grepformat=%f | grep 'expression' ## | cfdo argd % | bd`. The expression seems to work better when it's around single quotes for some reason too (I've tested with a word containing `\`` and it didn't work without the single quotes).

Comment: Great! Glad it's working for you. There may be other tweaks that make further improvements. I didn't dive deep on the edge cases. :)  Would you mind updating your question to match the new reality for the benefit of others who might be interested? Thanks.

Comment: You know what you might want to try? `set grepprg=grep\ -L\ $*`. The `$*` gets replaced with arguments by Vim. Probably more robust...may fix that problem with backticks/quotes.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question to fit with the final problem that I had. About the `$*`, I made the change but so far it seems to be working the same for the cases that I've tested. But I'll leave it inside the snippet since it may be more robust, thanks!